# Unable to post from a webforms project to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In a Visual Studio solution I have a webforms and a web api project. I want to post from an html page in the webforms project to the web api. The following is my code:

```
Code posting data to web api:

function SaveImage(dataURL) {
        dataURL = dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        var data = JSON.stringify(
                           {
                               id: 123,
                               value: dataURL
                           });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:65219/saveimage",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Done!");
            },
            error: onWebServiceFailed
        });
    }

The web api controller:

[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:54270/", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ImageController : ApiController
    {
    [Route("saveimage")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveImage([FromBody]ImageBinary imageBinary)
        {
            try
            {
                //Code to save image
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle exceptions
            }

            finally
            {
                //Cleanup code
            }

    }


//webapiconfig code:
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Web API routes
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        //config.EnableCors();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
    }

//Model class which will be sent to the web api
public class ImageBinary : IImageBinary
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that the web api code is never reached. When I check the developer tool in Chrome, I see the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:65219/saveimage. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: You should use route table rules which you specified [help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx). At least your request url should start from **/api/**.

Comment: you also have contentType defined twice with different values in your javascript call.  and don't have a dataType: "json" parameter at all. I also don't think processData does anything in your scenario.

Comment: Hi Fran, I removed the first contentType and added dataType : "json". Still it didn't post to the web api. I am getting the same errors.